# ComboBox items not updating when underlying ObservableCollection changes

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `ComboBox` and an `ObservableCollection` set as `DataSource` for that `ComboBox`.
When I programmatically add/remove items from the observable collection, nothing changes in the `ComboBox`.
What am I doing wrong?
Part 2: tried to put a `BindingSource` as a proxy for `ObservableCollection`. When programmatically added/removed items from `ObservableCollection`, no event like `ListChanged` or similar fired.
How can I make a `ComboBox` automatically update its list when underlying collection changes?

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        comboBox1.DataSource = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>(
            new []
            {
                new MyItem() { Name = "AAA"},
                new MyItem() { Name = "BBB"},
            });
    }

    private void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Nothing changes in the ComboBox when I add a new item to ObservableCollection
        ((ObservableCollection<MyItem>)(comboBox1.DataSource))
            .Add(new MyItem() { Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()});
    }
}

public class MyItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you set the data source? Also, please post your code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps to wrap a list in a `BindingList<T>`. Here a little test code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly List<string> _coll = new List<string> { "aaaaa", "bbbbb", "ccccc" };
    private readonly BindingList<string> _blist;
    private readonly Random _rand = new Random();
    private const string Templ = "mcvnoqei4yutladfffvtymoiaro875b247ytmlarkfhsdmptiuo58y1toye";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _blist = new BindingList<string>(_coll);
        comboBox1.DataSource = _blist;
    }

    private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = _rand.Next(Templ.Length - 5);
        string s = Templ.Substring(i, 5);
        _blist.Add(s);
    }
}
```

Note that you have to make the changes  (Add, Remove etc.) to the `BindingList`. The `BindingSource` works the same way.

Comment: Why doesn't ObservableCollection work if used instead of BindingList?

Comment: Note that my code snippet uses a `BindingList<T>`, not a `BindingSource`. `ObservableCollection` is a newer collection used primarily in WPF. It looks like it was not taken into account in the older winforms.

Comment: Ok, in the end the BindingList is only what works as expected. Accepted answer. I'm disappointed that MSDN is not too accurate.